# Delphi TNumberbox returns single; how to get to a standard integer?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

TNumberbox and TSpinEdit return values defined as type **single**.  I want to use these values to do simple integer arithmetic, but I can't cast them successfully to the more generalized integer type, and Delphi gives me compile-time errors if I try to just use them as integers.  This code, for example, fails with

> "E2010 Incompatible types: 'Int64' and 'Extended'":

```
var
    sMinutes: single;
    T: TDatetime;
begin
sMinutes :=Numberbox1.value;
T :=incminute(Now,sMinutes);
```

---

All I want to do here is have the user give me a number of minutes and then increment a datetime value accordingly. Nothing I've tried enables me to use that single in this way.

What am I missing??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just truncate the value before using it:

```
var
  Minutes: Integer;
  T: TDateTime;
begin
  Minutes := Trunc(NumberBox1.Value);
  T := IncMinute(Now, Minutes);
end;
```

Depending on your particular needs, you may need to use `Round` instead. It will correctly round to the nearest integer value, making sure that 1.999999999999 correctly becomes integer 2; `Trunc` would result in 1 instead. (Thanks to Heartware for this reminder.)

```
var
  Minutes: Integer;
  T: TDateTime;
begin
  Minutes := Round(NumberBox1.Value);
  T := IncMinute(Now, Minutes);
end;
```

[Trunc](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Trunc) and [Round](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Round) are in in the `System` unit.

Comment: Well that was easy!  Works like a charm.  Thanks for the instant response.

Comment: I would, however, use ROUND instead, as a value of 1.999999 is probably more correct in being interpreted as 2 and not as 1. And a value "very close to an integer value, but not quite there" is indeed very possible with floating point values - even if you have set up the control to only allow integer values.

Comment: @HeartWare, that's a good point. You should add that as an alternative answer. If for some reason you don't want to, I'll edit my answer to provide the info.

Comment: @HeartWare, I added it to my answer, but if you decide to add an answer I'll roll it back to the previous version.